# Is it the dropdown change event that trigger the filtering or the url change?

Tags: angular

Imagine you have a dropdown with multiple value to filter a table

When the user select a value, you do two things:

- Update the URL by adding a query parameter. This way you can pass the URL to someone else to see the same result
- You call a function to filter the table

My question/problem comes here.

If a user pass the URL with the parameter. In the init function of your component you need to subscribe to the queryParam to get the URL parameter. If you get a value from the URL you can do two things:

1. Filter the table and update the value of the dropdown without re-triggering the URL update
2. Update the dropdown value that will trigger the filtering without changing the URL

I don't understand who should trigger the filtering ? It seems that it can be either the URL or the dropdown select value change but with some conditional value to avoid looping over and over.

I'm quite new to angular. So maybe there is something I don't understand or there is a lot of code to make this work

Any advice on this topic ? I feel that this is a common problem as you can definitely see that in every webpage with filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Should be on page load, so the querystring should filter the results. Unless you want to make it solely front end, then the onchange event and query filter on initial load only.